# Multilanguage Website

Tags: multilingual

I'm building a website for the company of my parents. However they want multi-language support. I was thinking of the different ways to implement this. However I am curious as to the best practices and how to make the website have a minimal upkeep.

It's just a static front-end (based on Bootstrap) informative website without CMS or active conten management.

#### Solutions I came up with so far:

- Built all the pages twice in each language. Set the links manual: High upkeep
- Built a front-end js script that reroutes dependant on the language cookie set? (Is this even possible)

Are there other best practices to implement this without resorting to a clunky CMS like Drupal / WordPress ...

Comment: The simplest would be google translate, you can configure it [here](https://translate.google.com/manager/website/) for your website. It's basically a javascript that you will put on your website, and a language selector link. After the user will select the desired language the javascript will translate the whole website at once, when the user will reload the page or navigate to a different page there page will appear untranslated then in a few seconds the javacript will translate it once again. It's a bit frustrating but it's better than no translation or managing the translation your self.

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimal solution also depends on how extensive the site is, how many languages it contains, and what functionality, scalability or Online Marketing is required for the future. Drupal meets all these requirements also in terms of language switcher, different META-Tags etc. Okay, Drupal needs a bit workforce for understanding, structured way of working and documentation. Django is more programmer friendly which demands more technical but Drupal is more user friendly.

With little effort you can offer your websites in other languages with Google Translate: https://support.google.com/translate/answer/2534601?hl=en

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Definitly looking into those two.

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion to your solution of building pages twice. You can have a template:

```
home_page.html_template:
<body>
   <div> ${INTRODUCTION_TEXT} </div>
   <div> ${SOME_OTHER_TEXT} </div>
</body>
```

I.e. you code the whole page structure once, but don't specify what text will be added. You store translations for each piece of text in two languages in two different files. Then you run a script to generate separate html pages for each language.

You could even go one step further and use google translate API to translate text for you on the server side, before generating html.

Comment: So, could you then feed the appropriate text with PHP if you don't want to use JavaScript? Maybe, could it be possible to let a htaccess file decide which text to feed, based on the IP address/region?

Answer (score 0):

After thorough research: for a proper multilingual website which is easy to maintain. A framework / CMS is required:

- Wordpress
- Rails
- Django
- Drupal
- ...